# Как "отправить отзыв" со скриншотом и журналами?

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать окно "отправить отзыв" наподобие того, как это сделано в приложении Play Market?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. я бы хотела, чтобы текст пользователя со скриншотом и журналами отправлялся на мою почту (или в Android Developer Console). Насколько я знаю, общего способа сделать скриншот экрана в андроид не существует. Возможно ли это сделать это встроенными средствами Android, возможно, с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки от Google?

Comment: То есть вопрос в том, как сделать скриншот, а не как отправить его, я правильно понял? Сформулируйте вопрос чуть точнее и поправьте заголовок тогда.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, нет, немного не так. Интересует, есть ли возможность отправить скриншот и журналы (логи) так же, как это сделано в приложении Play Market.

Comment: Так кто вам мешает диалог такой же сверстать :) Получаете скриншот, тут вставляете его как картинку, и при отправке как файл. После нажатия можете обычный интент на почту кидать, только юзверю придется аж два раза тогда нажимать кнопку отправки. Но это лучше, чем логины-пароли от почты требовать. Иначе никак

Comment: Вот эти ребята дают скриншот на бесплатном уровне https://instabug.com/platforms/android